# how to import script with multiple statment with jpa and hibernate

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I use Jpa property `org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor`
for import ddl and dml file.

but files(special ddl files) that has multiple statement like: Procedures, Functions,... not property imported, because semicolon known as a statement to execute.

As at `MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor` [document](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/javadocs/org/hibernate/tool/hbm2ddl/MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor.html)

said:

> Class responsible for extracting SQL statements from import script. Supports instructions/comments and quoted strings spread over multiple lines. Each statement must end with semicolon.

`MultipleLinesSqlCommandExtractor` resolve statements that has multiple line, but create another problem in procedures that has multiple line that ends with semicolon.

I want to procedure scripts execute as a single statement.

In my case how to resolve it?  is there any other way to import ddl files to database using hibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not found any way in jpa-hibernate for resolve this.

For resolve this problem i use a third party library [mybatis](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mybatis/mybatis).

[document](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/getting-started.html).